# Does the avi networks controller work on VMware Fusion 7 or 8 on OS X?

Tags: devops, vmware-fusion

I'd like to try Avi on my laptop, but the OVA won't load into Fusion. This happens:

> Line 138: Unsupported element 'Property'

If I can't get it to work on my laptop, I guess I'll try it in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avi Controller is supported on VMWare Fusion with Ubuntu using "wget -qO- https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/avi-tm/avi_install | sh". 
Ubuntu VM needs to be 4 vCPU, 12 GB in order to run Controller and SE.

You can also try it in AWS or install in your lab. Checkout http://kb.avinetworks.com/try/

Comment: Is there some kind of tutorial or other documentation that shows what to do after it installs?