# How to configure a service engine to connect to the controller in Avi Vantage 16.1?

Tags: load-balancing

In my last question on Avi Vantage ([Does the avi networks controller work on VMware Fusion 7 or 8 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730481/does-the-avi-networks-controller-work-on-vmware-fusion-7-or-8-on-os-x)), I was instructed to execute a docker-based startup script. I've modified it slightly to take advantage of the latest Avi docker images (see below).

I'm able to get the Controller started and sort of configured via the web-based admin interface. But, the Service Engine (SE) doesn't ever connect to the Controller. I've confirmed that the SE docker container is running, but the Controller doesn't seem to see it. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot Avi service engine connections?

Here's my slightly modified installation and startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

controller_image="avinetworks/controller:16.1.1-9019-20160330.183143"
se_image="avinetworks/se:16.1.1-9019-20160330.183143"

# Quit the script if the user failed to provide the right password
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "Script is exiting because you failed to give root's password"
  exit 1
fi

command_exists() {
    command -v "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

avi_install_ubuntu() {
    echo -n "Starting Avi-Installation...\n"
    ######################################
    ####    Installing Docker 
    #####################################
    if command_exists docker && [ -e /var/run/docker.sock ]; then {
        echo -n "Skipping docker install\n"
    }
    else {
        echo -n "Proceedig with docker install\n"
        distro=$(awk '/DISTRIB_ID=/' /etc/*-release | sed 's/DISTRIB_ID=//' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') 
        if [ "$distro" = "ubuntu" ]; then {
            apt-get -y update
            apt-get -y install curl
            curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
        } else {
            systemctl disable firewalld
            systemctl stop firewalld
            yum -y install docker
            service docker start
        } fi
    }
    fi

        ######################################
        ####    Starting avi Controller
        #####################################
    echo -n "Starting Avi Controller container\n"
    int_name=`ip route|grep default|cut -d' ' -f 5`
    mgmt_ip=$(ip addr show $int_name | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | head -1)
        /usr/bin/docker run --name=avi_controller  --privileged=true -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8443:8443 -p 5098:5098 -d -t -e MANAGEMENT_IP=$mgmt_ip -v /var/lib/controller/var/log:/var/log -v /var/lib/controller/var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql -v /var/lib/controller/var/lib/avi:/var/lib/avi -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ${controller_image}

    echo -n "Starting Avi Service Engine container\n"
    /usr/bin/docker run -d --net=host -e NTHREADS=1 -e SEMEMMB=2048 -e "CONTROLLERIP=$mgmt_ip" --privileged=true ${se_image}

}

avi_install_ubuntu

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between Controller and ServiceEngine is secured by default. In addition to this, Controller also performs an admission control and only allows the Service Engines it knows about.

You can do a couple of things in this case:
- Set "allow_unauthenticated_nodes" in ControllerProperties object to True to disable the initial admission control. API to use is "/api/controllerproperties" and CLI is "configure controller properties"
-OR-
- You can checkout a secure token and insert it in the Service Engine. To generate the token, you can use the API "/api/securetoken-generate" and extract "auth_token" from the JSON payload of the response. You can then copy this token value to /var/lib/avi/certs/sc_auth_token in the ServiceEngine.

Pls. let us know if this works out for you.

Thanks,
Anand.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok. I've done all that, but it's still not connecting. I found another problem in the startup script (posted above) where the CONTROLLERIP environment variable wasn't being set properly. After fixing that and ensuring that the CONTROLLERIP variable is set properly, the service engine is still not connecting. What's the best way to troubleshoot this? Are there some logs in the service engine container I can look at to see what's happening?

Comment: Ok. I took another go at it. Setting 'allow_unauthenticated_nodes' to true now lets the SE successfully connect to the controller.  Unfortunately, now I don't know how to set the VIP. Any suggestions for how to configure the host and/or the controller/se docker containers so the service engine can respond to traffic on the VIP?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are referring to the configuration of VirtualService in the Avi Controller. Avi Controller will then place the Virtual Service on the Service Engine which activates the data path corresponding to this Virtual Service.

I am attaching some documentation related to this that you can look at for Virtual Service configuration:

- [Virtual Service Configuration](http://kb.avinetworks.com/docs/configuration-guide/applications/virtual-services/)
- [Link to API Guide](http://kb.avinetworks.com/docs/api-guide/) (You can look at the API for VirtualService and Pool)

Pls. let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Sort of, but not really. I'll ask a more specific question in another thread.

Comment: I decided this question warranted its own thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876251/how-to-setup-the-vip-in-avi-vantage-on-a-linux-cloud