# How to setup the VIP in Avi Vantage on a Linux Cloud

Tags: load-balancing

I've been trying to get Avi Vantage running on a single linux box using the docker installation method described here, using the "single host deployment" method:

http://kb.avinetworks.com/installing-avi-vantage-for-a-linux-server-cloud/

I've got the Controller and the Service Engine running and the Controller can see the Service Engine. Now, I'm trying to create a Virtual Service, but I'm not sure how to configure the Virtual IP (VIP).

What network interface should I bind the VIP to?

Answer (score 3):

VIP is bound to interface based on the reachability. This is done automatically by placement manager.

case-1
Say eth0 - 1.1.1.2/24 and when vip is in the same subnet (say 1.1.1.100), vs placement logic will choose eth0.

case-2: 
Say eth0 - 1.1.1.2/24 and when vip is in the different subnet (say 100.100.100.100), you can set the placement subnet in vs (advanced settings). That will force the vs to be placed on eth0

case-3:
The above can be done without placement subnet by using BGP. Configure BGP peers and enable_rhi in the VS (advanced_settings). VS will be placed on eth0 and additionally we will advertise vip though bgp. This will avoid manual configuration of routes to reach vip on the first hop router.

Comment: Ok, cool. Based on what you said, I figured it out. I needed to associate a secondary ip address to the NIC for the VIP. That was the crucial missing piece. It's all working now.